# The Multiple Choice Test Test

Tags: logical-deduction, no-computers

One day, the logic professor announces a pop quiz. "All questions in this test are about the test itself. In fact, the test is open note since you have a copy of the test itself. Good luck!"

**1.** What is the 1st question whose answer is B?

a. 1
b. 2
c. 3
d. 4
e. 5

**2.** The only 2 consecutive questions with identical answers are

a. 6, 7
b. 7, 8
c. 8, 9
d. 9, 10
e. 10, 11

**3.** The number of questions with answer E is

a. 0
b. 1
c. 2
d. 3
e. 4

**4.** The number of questions with answer A is

a. 4
b. 5
c. 6
d. 7
e. 8

**5.** This question and what question have the same answer?

a. 1
b. 2
c. 3
d. 4
e. 5

**6.** What is the answer to #17?

a. C
b. D
c. E
d. None of the above
e. All of the above

**7.** The answer to this question and the following question are how far apart alphabetically?

a. 4
b. 3
c. 2
d. 1
e. 0

**8.** How many questions have vowels as an answer?

a. 4
b. 5
c. 6
d. 7
e. 8

**9.** The *next* question with the same answer as this one is

a. 10
b. 11
c. 12
d. 13
e. 14

**10.** The answer to #16 is

a. D
b. A
c. E
d. B
e. C

**11.** The number of earlier (1-10) questions with answer B is

a. 0
b. 1
c. 2
d. 3
e. 4

**12.** The number of questions with consonants as an answer is

a. an even number
b. an odd number
c. a perfect square
d. prime
e. divisible by 5

**13.** The only odd-numbered problem with answer A is

a. 9
b. 11
c. 13
d. 15
e. 17

**14.** The number of questions with answer D is

a. 6
b. 7
c. 8
d. 9
e. 10

**15.** The answer to #12 is

a. A
b. B
c. C
d. D
e. E

**16.** The answer to #10 is

a. D
b. C
c. B
d. A
e. E

**17.** The answer to #6 is

a. C
b. D
c. E
d. none of the above
e. all of the above

**18.** the number of questions with answer A is also the number of questions with answer

a. B
b. C
c. D
d. E
e. none of the above

**19.** The answer to this question is

a. A
b. B
c. C
d. D
e. E

**20.** Of the following, which are great logicians?

a. Boole
b. De Morgan
c. Russell
d. Whitehead
e. All of the above

Hint:

> use the fact that each question has only 1 answer

Note: this puzzle is taken from the Mu Alpha Theta math competition. However, it earlier appeared in a slightly different form at http://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/srat-Q.txt.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold because it's an unacknowledged copy of someone else's work and we need to know whether OP got its creator's permission to post it here.

Comment: This is [James Propp's Self-Referential Aptitude Test](https://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/srat.html). @Display name, do you have Dr Propp's permission to post it here? (Even if you do, the question needs to give proper credit to its original author.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I did not copy Propp. In fact, I didn't even know he existed until you posted that link. Whether he is the original author is up for debate. If you're curious, I obtained the puzzle through a math competition, and there was no mention of his name at all.

Comment: Well, you copied _someone_ without attribution, even if you didn't know who the original author was! (Actually, they changed the last question, but not in a way that makes any difference to the puzzle.) So, anyway, here's the situation. 1. PSE policy -- and in fact policy on the whole Stack Exchange network -- is that copying material from elsewhere without attribution [is not allowed](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348). 2. _With_ suitable attribution, there's no violation of PSE policy as such, but [... continues]

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan How do we know that Propp is the original author? After all, the questions on that math competition are supposedly original. You raise a good point regarding citations, but until any doubt is cleared (or you prove that the creators of that math competition were blatantly copying Propp), I'm going to cite where I got this information.

Comment: ... if you don't have the permission of the original creator then you're probably breaking copyright law. It is _not_ the job of PSE moderators to be copyright police, and we will not remove things merely because they're copyright infringements (and there are actually legal reasons why we shouldn't start trying) -- but purely informally I'd request that other people's stuff not be copied here without their permission.

Comment: I don't think we _know_ that Propp is the original author, but on the page I linked to (and the other pages linked therefrom) he is clearly _claiming_ to be, and unless he's outright falsifying things there is plenty of evidence there that his claim to authorship goes back at least to the year 2000. Is the competition you mention older than that?

Comment: Also, by the way, if it's an _ongoing_ competition then I'm afraid there's another problem, because we don't allow questions from still-ongoing competitions here. (Though in this case forbidding it would be pretty pointless, if only because Propp's own page has complete solutions to the puzzle!)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan   Actually, this competition has been over for a long time now.

Comment: OK, then that issue doesn't arise. Out of curiosity, why do you prefer to say "Mu Alpha Theta competition" rather than giving (1) credit to the actual creator of the puzzle along with (2) a link behind which there is other material that will likely be interesting to people who enjoyed the puzzle? I mean, do you think Propp actually stole the puzzle from the Mu Alpha Theta competition (which year was it?) and faked up the emails etc. on his page?

Comment: I never claimed that Propp stole the puzzle from the Mu Alpha Theta organizers. On the contrary, I claim that we have no evidence that the organizers stole the puzzle from him.

Comment: I'm not claiming they stole it from him, or that they stole it at all. Just that he appears to be the _original creator_ of the puzzle and hence surely the best person to attribute it to, even if it happens that you encountered it via the Mu Alpha Theta competition. Evidently you disagree, and I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Alright. I've added that to the bottom of the answer so that future puzzlers are not confused.

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't be able to find the actual creator, as math competition problem committees tend to vary from year to year, and there is no data on the annual membership roster (beyond possibly a list of current members).

Comment: Once again, the actual creator is (unless he's lying about it) James Propp, so it doesn't matter who was on the Mu Alpha Theta problem committee. Anyway, this is now suitably attributed so I'll reopen it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My newest try

> Question 5 must match the answer of question 5, since there is only one answer that is correct for each question.  So 5 is E and 1-4 can not be E.

Thus

> Question 10 is linked to Question 16, and the only one that matches both ways is 10 - A and 16 - D

Thus

> Question 17 is linked to Question 6, the only way that can be is if one is B and the other is D.  Since 16 is D and 16 and 17 can't have the same answer (from Q2), then 6 is D and 17 is B.

Thus

> Question 13 says only one odd question can have answer A.  It can't be A-13 (which would mean 13 and 9 do), B-11 because question 1 says there is a B in the first 5 questions and so 11 cant be A, C-13 because then 13 would not be A, E-17 from previous result.   So 13 is D and 15 is A.  Which means 12 is A.

Thus

> Question 20 should be E

So

> Question 3 is the number of Es.  It can not be E-4 because then D-3 would also be true.  We already have two Es (20 and 5), so 3 is C-2 or D-3

So

> Question 1 is the first B answer.  This can not be A-1 nor B-2 because these are contradictions.  Also, we know from Q5, that it can't be E-5.  and C-3 is wrong because Q3 is C or D.  So Q1 is D-4.  This means that Q4 is B.

So

> Q8 counts the number of A and E answers.  from Q4, we know there are 5 As and Q3 says there are 2 or 3 Es, so Q8 is D-7 or E-8.

So

> Q8 must be E-8 because Q-7 is B,C,D,or E and since Q8 can't be A or B or C from previous answers, Q8 is E in each situation. So Q3 must be D-3.

So

> Because Q4 is B-5, we know there are 5 As.  3 are known (10, 15, 12).  The only two left that can be A (because of contradictions or because 9,10 can't both be A because 2 can't be D because 1 is D) are 2 and 18, so Q2 is A and Q18 is A.

So

> Because Q2 is A, Q6 and Q7 are the same so Q7 is D.

So

> Because Q7 is D, Q8 must be E or C, but it can't be C so Q8 is E.  This means Q3 must be D (there are 3 Es).

So

> Q11 must be 1 or 2 so must be B or C.  But if Q9 is B, Q11 is B and False.  So Q9 must be D and Q11 is B.

So

> Q14 can only be B or C so the number of Ds is 7 or 8.  The maximum number of Ds is 7 (So Q14 is B) and that means that Q19 is B which makes Q18 A.

Thus the answers are:

> 1-D
>  2-A
>  3-D
>  4-B
>  5-E
>  6-D
>  7-D
>  8-E
>  9-D
>  10-A
>  11-B
>  12-A
>  13-D
>  14-B
>  15-A
>  16-D
>  17-B
>  18-A
>  19-B
>  20-E

Comment: You say rot13(Dhrfgvba 20 fubhyq or R) in your solution, then arrive at a different letter at the end. Check your solution for mistakes.

Comment: Oops. so I did.  Typo in the solution list is fixed now. 
 Thanks @Displayname

Comment: Actually, I never noticed it until now, but your answer list purports that there are rot13(6 Q'f, juvyr lbhe nafjre gb dhrfgvba 14 pynvzf gung gurer ner 7).

Comment: @Displayname found my mistake I think.  An incorrect assumption on Q3.  Corrected i hope.

Comment: Now your answer to question 11 is contradictory to the answer list.

Comment: @Displayname i think i got it now.... if only no typos

Comment: $\,$ $\,$ $\,$      Good job.

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL ANSWER:**

> From **Q1** we know that **Q1**, **Q2**, **Q3**, **Q4** or **Q5** is **B**. We know it cannot be **Q1** because that would mean the answer would have to be **A and B**. Similarly, it cannot be **Q2**, because then **Q1** would be the first **B**. It can also not be **Q5** as this would cause **Q2** to become the first B. This leaves us with **C** (**Q3**) and **D** (**Q4**), from which I cannot continue.
>
> Next, I'll consider **Q10** and **Q16**. These will cause a paradox unless **Q10** is **A** and **Q16** is **D**. Two questions down, eighteen to go.
>
> **Q13** provides a pleasant surprise. This rules out **A** in **Q3, Q5, Q7, Q19,** and finally **Q13** because it being **A** would cause **Q9** to also be **A**, but there is only one odd-numbered question with answer **A**. We can also rule out **Q13** being answered by
>
> Similarly to **Q10** and **Q16, Q6** and **Q17** will cause a paradox unless their answers are **B** and **D**. However, unlike **Q10** and **Q16**, we do not know which letter answers which question.
>
> **Q20** is easy enough. Since there are logicians named George **Boole**, Augustus **De Morgan**, Bertrand **Russell** and Alfred North **Whitehead**, the only feasible answer is **E**.
>
> **Q12** tells us the amount of answers with consonants (**B, C** or **D**) is either: odd, even, square, prime or divisible by 5. Since a number cannot be neither odd or even, **C, D** or **E** must all be incorrect. The only numbers between one and twenty that aren't square, prime or divisible by 5 are **6, 8, 12, 14** and **18**. From **Q8** we can figure out that the amount of consonants must be **16, 15, 14, 13** and **12**. Crossing this with our **Q12** answers we discover there are only possibilities **12** and **14**.  We also know **Q12** is **A**.
>
> **Q15** asks us for the answer to **Q12** as its own. This means the answer to **Q15** is **A**.
>
> However, **Q2** teels us there is only one situation in which two identical questions have the same answer. Since **Q16** and **Q17** are not one of the options for **Q2**, **Q17** cannot be **D** and must therefore be **B** This also means **Q6** is **D**.
>
> Current Position:
>
> **Q1: C or D**
>
> **Q2: ?**
>
> **Q3: Not A**
>
> **Q4: ?**
>
> **Q5: Not A**
>
> **Q6: D**
>
> **Q7: Not A**
>
> **Q8: C or E**
>
> **Q9: ?**
>
> **Q10: A**
>
> **Q11: ?**
>
> **Q12: A**
>
> **Q13: Not A**
>
> **Q14: ?**
>
> **Q15: A**
>
> **Q16: D**
>
> **Q17: B**
>
> **Q18: ?**
>
> **Q19: Not A**
>
> **Q20: E**

Please post suggestions in the comments if you have any, it would be of great help.

Comment: "The only numbers between one and twenty that aren't square, prime or divisible by 5 are 2, 3, 7, 11, 13, 17 and 19." This is wrong, so you'll have to go back to that point.

Comment: @a guy. Yes. Did you read the 2nd sentence of my comment?

Comment: There we go. Fixed.